# Read position of UIPickerView while scrolling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIPickerView with custom cells. For every moment, I'd like to know which cell is in the center location (behind the tinted selection indicator). The UIPickerView delegate method

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

does provide this information, but only after the picker view has stopped. What I'm looking for is a way to retrieve the currently "selected" cell while the picker view is still spinning and has not yet come to a halt.

As a work around, I've tried to go through KVO and register for each cell's view changes:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    .
    .
    [cell addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld|NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}
```

I do receive callbacks to `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`, however no matter whether I scroll the picker view up or down, the received values seem to be always the same:

```
2011-03-09 08:00:34.429 Project[35069:207] Frame: x=2.00, y=-13.00
2011-03-09 08:00:34.430 Project[35069:207] Location: x=4.00, y=-26.00
2011-03-09 08:00:34.430 Project[35069:207] Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = "NSRect: {{2, -13}, {118, 70}}";
    old = "NSRect: {{2, -13}, {118, 70}}";
}
2011-03-09 08:00:34.431 Project[35069:207] Frame: x=2.00, y=-13.00
2011-03-09 08:00:34.431 Project[35069:207] Location: x=4.00, y=-26.00
2011-03-09 08:00:34.432 Project[35069:207] Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = "NSRect: {{2, -13}, {118, 70}}";
    old = "NSRect: {{2, -13}, {118, 70}}";

(Location coordinates are in window frame)
```

Any other ideas what I could try to get that value?

Answer (score 4):

I think the method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view`
```

with:

```
[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]);
```

Is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your picker delegate's `-pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` method to give you a pretty good idea of where the picker's wheel is. As you scroll in one direction or the other, the picker will ask its delegate for the title (or view) for a row. The number of rows between the "center" of the wheel and the row the picker is asking for depends on the row height, but you'll likely know what that is.

You'll have to experiment a bit to get it right. The picker seems to ask for one or two rows that aren't yet visible, perhaps to keep the scrolling smooth. In my test with a picker that displays 5 rows, there seems to be about a 3-row difference between the row the picker was asking for and the center. You'll obviously also have to keep track of the direction of rotation (up or down), and you won't find out if the first or last two or three rows are selected until your `-pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:` is called.

Comment: I saw this idea somewhere else, but it seems a bit unsafe. You never know how many views will be exactly preloaded. The number might vary in different iOS versions, maybe also depending on the device's memory availability. I've looked up in the documentation, but could not find anything specified in that regard.

Comment: There are definitely no guarantees, and as I mentioned above the technique isn't without flaws. I'd absolutely recommend thorough testing. Short of rolling your own picker view, though, I think it's the closest you'll get to real-time notification of changes to the picker.

Comment: I do this, where I check that every change is consecutive, as pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:  pre-fetches rows in a random manner, so I keep the old row somewhere and act only if it is one up or one down: ˜if (row == self.oldrow + 1 || row == self.oldrow - 1)˜

Answer (score 2):

I think this is interesting.  I wanted to do the similar thing with UIPicker, but haven't looked into much yet.

UIDatePicker actually does this, you can drag time around noon and it will toggle AM/PM even though the finger has not lifted from the screen (it should not have called "didSelectRow" yet).

UIDatePicker actually subclasses from UIControl, instead of UIView like UIPickerView.  So, UIDatePicker is probably observing all UIControlEvents to do this.

Observing -pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent probably works for now, but if behavior changes later (ie caching behavior, ie) is changed, this will break...

One suggestion is to try KVO on center property, instead of frame.

Edit1: By the way, how does your observeValueForKeyPath method look like?

Edit2: Upon further research, it seems most of UIKit is not KVO compliant.
   See this answer - 
[Key value Observing during UIView Animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555690/key-value-observing-during-uiview-animations)

So, it seems like only option is to keep poling for the view's value when it's visible.  How about forloop and pole frame/center property whenever it's in view?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought, but you could add a UIScrollView (transparent with a contentView that is as tall as the number of components.) over the UIPickerView.

Then listen to the UIScrollViewDelegate methods to get the live scrolling data you need.

The tricky part would be passing along the touch events from the scroller to the picker so that it would act as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have with UIPickerView is that the view you are setting for the cells are actually subViews.
UIPickerView is built from various imageViews, a TableView and a selection line. 
The view you provide when using viewForRow are inserted as subViews of the tableView's cells and so their frame is never changed. 
The only frame that changes is the frame of the actual tableView cell, to which of course you have no access.

A possible solution is to simply replace the UIPickerView's tableView with your own.

You can do this by setting the number of rows for the UIPickerView to be 0, and place a transparent tableView over the UIPickerView. Your tableView will hold the actual cells, and since a UITableView inherits from UIScrollView, you can get events about the scroll and simply check which UITableViewCell is currently under the selection line.

Answer (score 0):

The frame does not change because the cell is not moving. One of its superviews is, and the cell is carried along with it. To figure out the cell's coordinate in the parent `UIPickerView`, try this:

```
CGRect theApparentRect = [theCell convertRect: theCell.bounds toView: thePicker];
```

The resultant rectangle will be in the coordinate system of `thePicker`, and you can then figure out if it's in the middle with the following simple test:

```
CGPoint middleOfThePicker = CGPointMake
(
    CGRectGetMidX(thePicker.bounds),
    CGRectGetMidY(thePicker.bounds)
);
Boolean isInMiddle = CGRectContainsPoint(theApparentRect, middleOfThePicker);
```

Comment: I am already doing this with the frame's origin. Don't think it makes any difference whether I transform the bounds or the frame's origin?

Comment: Nope, though the origin of the cell may or may not line up with the visible bounds of the container view. Try with the full rect and see?