# How to detect UIPickerView central row when spinning

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

Because of lack of screen space, i try to display description (UILabel appearing right to pickerView when spinning) of image in UIPickerView when user spins the wheel. I use viewForRow: to detect the spin and to show the description. The problem is, using the code i've written so far, it can't display the description of first 2 rows and last 2 rows. 
Here is my code:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIImageView *image=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[zodiacSigns objectAtIndex:row]]]autorelease];
    selectedZodiac.frame=CGRectMake(80, 80, 50, 50);
    selectedZodiac.hidden=NO;
    @try {
    //Here -2 is offset of the view in central row
        selectedZodiac.text=[zodiacSigns objectAtIndex:row-2];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception caught");
    }
    @finally {

    }
    if([yourZodiacPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]!=0)
    {
        [self.view insertSubview:selectedZodiac aboveSubview:self.view];
    }
    NSLog(@"reuseView");
    return image;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe someone could just tell how to detect whether user spins wheel up or down? I will handle it over there

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do with the -2 offset. Why not show the description for the central row by removing the -2? Could you try to elaborate on your problem?

Comment: @Pol Mum We need -2 offset, because viewForRow: method is called only when new view is pushed on to the uipickerview. that means, that [row] corresponds to the last object in UIPickerView (when user spins down) and to the topmost object in UIPickerView (when user spins up), but not the central object. and the difference between the last object at the end of UIPickerView and the central object is -2. I hope it helps to clear the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the best way would to recreate the PickerView with a ScrollView/TableView and a matching overlay image if you really need this functionality.

Disable selection/highlight and scroll to the nearest "cell" when the scrollview stops.

Then determinate the cell that is in the middle of the screen.
You should also add a view before and after the content, so the user can move the first/last cell to the middle of the screen.

Comment: Good idea. You could start with this to accomplish that: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/01/longer-spinning-blurring.html

Answer (score -1):

I might have misunderstood, but if what you want is to display a description of the image currently selected, you should implement pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent: and set the description label there, instead of doing it in viewForRow:forComponent:. It would be something like this:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    selectedZodiac.frame=CGRectMake(80, 80, 50, 50);
    selectedZodiac.hidden=NO;
    selectedZodiac.text=[zodiacSigns objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

This way you would always be displaying the description of the selected picker row.

Comment: thanks for response, but i need to display description only when spinning, not when user selects a row. Description appears when user spins the wheel and disappears when user selects a row. didSelectRow: is not called when user spins the wheel, it's only called when the wheel stops. For now, i only need to figure out how to detect whether user spins wheel up or down. this way i could find out a central row by applying -2 offset when user spins down and +2 when it spins up. anyway, thanks for response

Comment: @blackhawk4152 Hmmm, i see. There's no easy solution to your problem. I similar question was asked here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237696/read-position-of-pickerview-while-scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237696/read-position-of-pickerview-while-scrolling), but they didn't arrive to a good solution. Check it out, but it might be easier to do something different.