# DatePicker issue in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uidatepicker

I am new to Swift. In my app, I have a date picker concept. My issue is when select date button, date picker is appearing fine suppose I select `DEC 20 2015`. My issue is when scroll date picker wheel very fast and press done button on my date picker tool bar date is not picking . If I open date picker I want to show previously selected date example `DEC 20 2015`. But it shows some other dates when I scroll faster.

```
var datePicker:UIdatePicker
func dateselcted()
{
    var date:NSDate = NSDate()
    datePicker.minimumdate = date
    if cell.dateText.characters.count == 0
    {
        //If user not select any date I am showing current date  and working fine
        var dateOb:AnyObject = 
        datePicker.setdate(date ,animated:false)
    }
    else
    {
        // Suppose user select DEC 20 2015 storing this date in one object example below and working fine but it is fails when scroll datepicker wheel very fast then it is showing the other date how to show "DEC 20 2015 " when picker wheel scrolls fastly I want to show date what I selected

        var dateOb:AnyObject = DEC 20 2015 
        datePicker.setdate( dateOb as nsdate ,animated:false)
    }    
}
```

Comment: yes  I want  to stop wheel before press done button is it possible?otherwise how to show previous selected date when picker appears

Answer (score 1):

A date picker only invokes it's action method when the wheels stop spinning. You don't get called continuously as the wheels spin from value to value.

It doesn't look like there is any facility to do what you want (get notified of value changes as the wheels in the date picker spin.)

Furthermore, I don't think the value of a date picker (or a regular UIPickerView) changes until it stops spinning, so it will still have it's old value if you start it spinning and click the button before it stops.

Comment: what u said is correct but my issue is how to set date old date when picker appears every time

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. date pickers have a date property. If you want to set it to a particular date, use code like `datePicker.date = someDate`. That will set the date picker to the specific date you want.

Answer (score 0):

Are you waiting for the scrolling to stop before pressing your done button? That may be your issue.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237696/read-position-of-pickerview-while-scrolling) may have what you are looking for.

The delegate

```
pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

is not called until the picker stops spinning. If you need to determine the selected row while spinning, you will need to write some logic to guess the state when done is pressed.

Comment: yes  I want  to stop wheel before press done button is it possible?otherwise how to show previous selected date when picker appears.i followed set date but it`s fails when picker scrolls fastly

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to select a date like you do and still expect the date picker picking your desired date automatically. The device does not know what we think. Normally, users won't press a button until they see that date gets selected. So, I think your concern is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can first set datePicker.date to [NSDate date], then set datePicker.date to previously selected date. the OC code for you:

```
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
datePicker.date = date;
```

It works for me, but I don't know why.