# How to detect values from UIPickerView while is rolling?

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I'm trying to read data from a UIPickerView while is rolling.

Didselectedrow is giving you back row value only when UIPicker is not moving. How can I catch values from UIPickerView while is rolling?

I need to know exactly the passing data over the center row, get them and update other objects into UIView accordingly.

I tried to call a reading function using a timer, but didselectedrow does not update himself while rolling, see code below:

```
// define the timer
let cycleTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.readUIPicker), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

as timer was defined it call reading func every 0.1s

```
// read UIPicker
func readUIPicker() {
    let  selectedRow = myPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

    // Do something here based on selectedRow value
    print("SelectedRow = \(selectedRow)")
}
```

The problem is that selectedRow will update only as soon as the rolling motion is stopped. No way to have control over passing elements.

Comment: I don't think you can do that... At least it's not available on the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate

Comment: Why would you need to do this? You can tell the current setting before a spin; you know the final setting once it stops/is selected; and you know what all the intermediate values are that are passed in between because you input the options for the picker in the first place. What other info are you trying to determine?

Comment: See if the scroll indicator insets might help or `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read position of UIPickerView while scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237696/read-position-of-uipickerview-while-scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

While there is no API to get the picker's value while scrolling, the picker view will be calling your data source and delegate methods to get the title or view for a given row so it can be displayed as the user scrolls the picker view. So the best you can do is make use of the fact that the picker view just asked for the title or view of some row. But that row isn't necessarily the current center row.