# How can I make the value change during the animation? Wheel Picker SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, picker

Wheel Picker has an animation and only fixes the value when the animation is complete.
How can I make the value change during the animation?
The problem is that if the user clicks save before the animation is complete, it will save the previous value and not the new one.

Conventionally, the change occurs from 10 to 15 upon completion of the animation.
And I want the value to change 10 11 12 13 14 15 during the animation.[image]

```
Picker(selection: $selectedReps, label: Text("Reps")) {
                                    ForEach(minValue+1...maxValue, id: \.self) {
                                        Text("\($0)")
                                            .foregroundColor(Color("lightGreenColor"))
                
                                    }
                                }
                                .onChange(of: selectedReps) { newValue in
                                            selectedReps = newValue
                                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear to be any way to do this.
The Picker accepts a binding, and there is no way to interject or change when it decides to update this value.

You can either use another picker style to circumvent this problem, or use UIPickerView (see here [Read position of UIPickerView while scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237696/read-position-of-uipickerview-while-scrolling)).

You could also probably define your own picker style (or just a custom view) to mimic this behavior in SwiftUI, but you will lose out on a lot of native functionality (as in any custom solution).